# nodeJS, MySQL and UTF8

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a custom String.Prototype function:

```
String.prototype.Apos = function () {
        var string = this.innerHTML.toString();
        return string.replace(/â€™/g,"'").replace(/â€œ|â€/g,'"');
    };
```

I really just want to write a utf8 string to the browser using javascript, however using `decodeURIComponent` wont work and so I have just resorted to replacing the apostrophes myself.

So from the examples I've seen I wrote the above function, however it doesnt seem to return anything.  When I run the following:

`$("span").html(string.Apos);`

I don't get a response.  I've never written a custom prototype function before so could someone help me out and tell me where Im going wrong?

Comment: Try to perform `SET NAMES utf8` query right after mysql connected.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to mess with string.prototype?

You can write a function to do the specific job you want to perform, i.e., replace text.

```
function replaceQuotes(i, oldHtml) {
    return oldHtml.toString().replace(/â€™/g,"'").replace(/â€œ|â€/g,'"');
}
```

And then:

```
$("span").html(replaceQuotes);
```

Comment: No i don't, but it seems to be commonly used and i wanted to learn how it works. My attempt seemed to call and i didn't know why.

Comment: You'd want to attach functions to string.prototype if you want all string objects to have access to the function as a method.  Your use case is so specific that I doubt it makes sense for all string objects to have this method.